# Time format in Excel is getting messed up

Tags: excel, excel-formula, datetime-format

I wrote 955:00:00 for 955 hours in excel however, it is getting stored as `08-02-1900  19:00:00` when I run `hours()` function on it then it gives me 19. I am not able to make sense of why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Excel stores all date/time values as the number of days since 31/12/1899. Any times over 24 hours are treated as being a day. You can simply format the cell as [hh]:mm:ss if you want to see hours over 24. For calculations, simply multiply the cell value by 24.